# Scaling MATLAB/Octave plot so that all the labels can be printed properly

Tags: matlab, plot, label, scale, heatmap

I am trying to create a simple heatmap using MATLAB/Octave:
[image: Heatmap plot]

As you can see I have a lot of rows, each of which represents a separate category.

I am using the `imagesc` function and I would like to be able to scale the image/plot so that each of the y-axis labels could be printed properly (instead of having the mess that can be seen in the image below).

Here is a sample code that I would like to modify:

```
A = randi(100, 200, 3);
imagesc(A, limit = [0, 100]);
set(gca, 'xtick', [1:3]);
set(gca, 'xticklabel', { "1,000", "2,000", "3,000" });
set(gca, 'ytick', [1:200]);
```

Edit: I am attaching the solution to the proposed problem, reached thanks to EitanT's advice as well as the useful information at http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/73290.html?nojs=1:

```
paperWidth = 16.5;
paperHeight = 11.7;

set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches');
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [paperHeight paperWidth]);
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual');
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 paperWidth paperHeight]);
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters'); figure(gcf);

A = randi(100, 200, 3);
imagesc(A, limit = [0, 100]);
set(gca, 'FontSize', 5);
set(gca, 'FontWeight', 'light');
set(gca, 'xtick', [1:3]);
set(gca, 'xticklabel', { "1,000", "2,000", "3,000" });
set(gca, 'ytick', [1:200]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions to this:

#### Resizing the figure window

If the figure is not maximized already, you can do it using:

```
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0, 'ScreenSize'))
```

Instead of `get(0, 'ScreenSize')` you can, of course, specify any desired dimensions with a custom vector (as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html?s_tid=doc_12b)).

#### Reducing the font size

You can also make the label text smaller simply by decreasing the font size:

```
set(gca, 'FontSize', 5)
```

Note that this, however, affects *all* text in the current axes.

#### Reducing the number of displayed ticks

As a last resort, you can reduce the number of displayed ticks in the y-axis, *i.e* increase the tick interval. Instead of `1:200`, try playing with other intervals, for instance:

```
set(gca, 'YTick', [1:20:200])
```

Try a combination of the solutions described above, for better visualization.

You can read more about axis control in [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/individual-axis-control.html). Also, as suggested by you in one of the comments, [this page](http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/73290.html?nojs=1) contains a lot of additional useful tricks for displaying plots in MATLAB.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply! Whilst this would apply well if I had categories containing 10 or 20 rows each, I'm afraid this is inapplicable to my problem, since I would like to keep all 200 rows (along with their labels) on the plot, and just scale it in such way, so that the label text would be distinguishable. Hope that makes sense. Thanks very much again!

Comment: @Hristo In my answer, the plot would still remain the same, everything will be drawn just as before. It's just that not all ticks (=labels) will be displayed. Are you implying in your comment that you want display ALL labels? I'm not sure there's enough room on the figure.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Hence, I was asking if there would be a way to scale the picture (referred to as "image/plot" above) up so that all of the labels can be displayed at the same time. Would that be possible at all?

Comment: Not sure. You should either reduce the label font size OR resize the figure window itself (just manually maximize it and see what happens). I revised my answer accordingly, please see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much again for your reply! It kind of pointed me in the right direction (or at least one that helps me find a workaround for that problem). The following combination works well: `set(gca,'FontSize', 5);
set(gca,'FontWeight','light');`, whereas the suggested `set(get(gca,'YLabel'), 'FontSize', 5)`, strangely enough, did not change anything.

Comment: @Hristo I'm not near MATLAB right now, so unfortunately I didn't have the chance to test it out. If you say `set(gca, 'FontSize', ...)` works, then I'll correct my answer for future reference.

Comment: `set(gca, 'FontSize'..)` works but affects the scale of all axes, which is not ideal in the case. The approach you gave me here, as I mentioned in one of my comments above, just gives me a partial workaround (thus marking the answer only as useful, instead of accepting it). The solution for scaling up my plot so that all the labels can be read normally is a different one, and I would mark an answer that directly solves that problem (since at the moment I am still unable to read the labels but just try to infer from their size about the actual textual content) as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: @Hristo I'm assuming that you already tried maximizing the figure window and the labels still overlap, so we can deduce that "you cannot fit in all labels on the y-axis at a sufficiently readable font size without them being overlapping". With that being said, lets try to attack this problem from the other direction. How would you like the labels to be displayed then?

Comment: When I maximize the window manually, it brings the scale up to a bit more reasonable level, but I would ideally like to be able to do that programmatically, i.e. have a reasonably sized (meaning readable font, without needing to zoom in explicitly when viewing an exported image) plot, which in the case has to be achieved by somehow scaling everything up. I was thinking of replicating each row of my data a given number of times and then only displaying the Y-labels with a certain step (i.e. instead of all) but that wound not be the most practical solution. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Hristo If you're willing to give up on showing all labels, then you already know how to do it (it is also written in the answer). But you say it would not be practical for you. So what would be?

Comment: As I said above, I would like to be able to scale up the plot programmatically (i.e. a controlled way of "maximizing" the window manually), whilst keeping the font size normal, and displaying all the labels (since they represent distinct categories, not ordered in any particular way).

Comment: Try maximizing the figure window using `set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'))`...

Comment: That, along with the useful tricks provided on the the following page http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/73290.html?nojs=1, seems to have solved the problem. The good thing is that instead of `get(0,'Screensize')`, a vector like `[1 1 3000 3000]` can be given as a parameter and this would automatically scale the plot (which would work appropriately only if the paper is scaled up as well). Thanks very much for your help again! May I ask you to, please, update your answer above with your latest suggestion? I am marking it as accepted.